# Wrong indent with emacs 24 and 25 in shell-script-mode?

Tags: indentation, shell

I get the following indentation for my bash script

```
for i in *; {
    echo $i
}
         echo done
```

The last indent is wrong and should be zero spaces.

How can this be fixed?

Comment: I removed the part about Emacs 25 because I see the same thing in Emacs 24.5.

Comment: Alright. Although I just realized seeing it recently after switching to emacs 25 from 24 and I also don't see it on emacs 23. Maybe it just started on a recent emacs 24 or I just happened to not notice. Anyway thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: Use `for i in *; do ... end`?

Comment: The workaround is `do ... done`. But I think someone needs to file an emacs bug report.

Comment: It's not a workaround; `do ... done` is the only documented syntax: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Looping-Constructs.html

Comment: ... which I like to consider as a shortcoming of the documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have reported this as emacs bug 25768 at

https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=25768.

However, this is not the only indentation problem. More can be found in the [emacs bug tracker](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/pkgreport.cgi?package=emacs;include=subject%3Aindentation) and others should be reported via `M-x report-emacs-bug`.

Comment: FYI indentation is not provided by any single library in Emacs, so there's no one problem area, or thing to "overhaul". The indentation code for a given mode may (or may not) be 100% unique to that mode.